# Array To Matrix

Tags: java, array, matrix

I made a method that takes an array and converts it to a matrix, given that it is a valid conversion.  However, there is some redundant code in the beginning and I thought maybe you could help me? I am new to programming so avoid complicated imports and such.

```
    private int[][] toMatrix(int[] arr) {

    if(validConversion(arr)){
        int index = 0;
        //redundant
        int row = (int) Math.sqrt(arr.length);
        int col = (int) Math.sqrt(arr.length);

        int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];
        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<col; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = arr[index];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    return null;
}


boolean validConversion(int[] arr) {
    return arr.length == 1 || arr.length % Math.sqrt(arr.length) == 0;
}
```

Comment: The method name should really be called `toSquareMatrix()`

Answer (score 5):

```java
private int[][] toMatrix(int[] arr) {
```

Don't shorten names just because you can.

---

```java
if(validConversion(arr)){
```

This does not need to be an extra function, actually, especially if you drop the "1" special case. An array of one item can technically be converted to a matrix with one item...it's just not much of a matrix.

```java
int matrixSize = (int) Math.sqrt(array.length);

if ((array.length % matrizSize) == 0) {
```

You can also reuse `matrixSize` now.

---

```java
        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<col; j++){
```

I'm a very persistent advocate for that you're only allowed to use single-letter variable names when dealing with dimensions. In this case, using `column` and `row` would make the code very nicely readable:

```java
for (int row = 0; row < matrixSize; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < matrixSize; column++) {
        matrix[row][column] = array[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

`index++` could be rolled into the assignment:

```java
matrix[row][column] = array[index++];
```

I'm torn whether that actually improves readability or not, though.

---

```java
boolean validConversion(int[] arr) {
```

Members and functions without an explicit visibility modifier are `package-private`. In my opinion, `package-private` should be avoided as it easily can lead to unhealthy couplings between classes in the same package.

---

Consider whether you want to perform additional error checks and throw `IllegalArgumentException`s if they don't add up, for example when the given array is `null` and so on.

Comment: An alternative rule (which I follow) for single-character names is that *the larger the scope, the more descriptive the name*.  Loop index variables that span 2 or 3 lines ought to be very short, probably a single character.  Whereas the function parameter has much greater scope and should be longer.

Comment: @TobySpeight My point with that rule is, that every line should be readable on its own, without having to go hunting for definitions (too much). As an example, `performCalculation(i, j)` and `performCalculation(groupIndex, rowIndex)`.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing - just a different means to similar ends.  I don't go so far as "a single line on its own", but a small group of lines (e.g. such as this `for` loop) should be intelligible.  Readers can choose what's right for them.  Great answer, by the way!

Answer (score 4):

We could evaluate the square root just once:

```
    int width = (int)Math.sqrt(arr.length);
    if (width * width != arr.length) {
        // not square - invalid
        return null;
    }

    int height = width  // not really needed, since we know matrix is square
```

It's not clear why you reject arrays of 0 or 1 elements, so I removed that test.

We should consider throwing an exception (perhaps `InvalidArgumentException`?) rather than returning a null object when the test fails.